# Nested for...in statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn JavaScript in Codecademy and one of the things mentioned briefly are "for in" loops. I've used them in a few of the exercises, but in this case I can't get it to work. I could do it with for (i = blah; etc), but I'd like to know what's wrong with this and if there's a way to fix it:

```
//Your three dimensional array from the last exercise probably
//looked something like this:
var hands = [];
hands[0] = [ [3,"H"], ["A","S"], [1,"D"], ["J","H"], ["Q","D"] ];
hands[1] = [ [9,"C"], [6,"C"], ["K","H"], [3,"C"], ["K","H"] ];

//Loop over every dimension in the array, logging out the suit and rank
//of each card in both hands
//1. loop over each hand
for (var hand in hands) {
//2. loop over each card array in each hand
    for (var card in hand) {
        //3. loop over each rank/suit array for each card in each hand
        for (var prop in card) {
            //4. log the value of the rank/suit array item
            console.log(card[prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is 0 0 0, instead of the number and suit. I tried placing console.log() after the first and second loop and I noticed it works correctly in the first, but not in the second one.

Comment: Don't use `for...in` on arrays

Comment: `for...in` does **not** iterate over the values of an object, it iterates over the property names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Momentarily ignoring the `for-in` issue, your inner loops should look like this...

```
for (var hand in hands) {
    for (var card in hands[hand]) {
        for (var prop in hands[hand][card]) {
            console.log(hands[hand][card][prop]);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that each inner loop needs to explicitly reference the current value of its outer loop. You are iterating over the keys (the variable before `in`) instead.

---

To deal with Arrays properly, you should almost always use a `for` loop instead of `for-in`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < hands.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < hands[i].length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < hands[i][j].length; k++) {
            console.log(hands[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

There are a few reasons for this, which you can find on StackOverflow.

---

To add clarity to the code, you can cache the current item in a variable...

```
for (var i = 0; i < hands.length; i++) {
    var hand = hands[i]
    for (var j = 0; j < hand.length; j++) {
        var cards = hand[j];
        for (var k = 0; k < cards.length; k++) {
            console.log(cards[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `for..in` loops on arrays, since it doesn't just loop over the indexed members of the array, but all properties of the object. Instead, you can use a 'traditional' `for` loop, or the ECMAScript 5 `.forEach`

```
var hand, card, prop, h, c, p;

for (h = 0; h < hands.length; ++h) {
    hand = hands[h];
    for (c = 0; c < hand.length; ++c) {
        card = hand[c];
        for (p = 0; p < card.length; ++p) {
            prop = card[p];
            console.log(prop);
        }
    }
}
```

There are shorter ways to do the above, but that's a basic and readable method.